# How to merge sub-sub-arrays and add their lengths by the sub-array index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sub-array

I have an array with some sub-arrays (the code below describes a situation where each sub-array has two sub-sub-arrays, that number can vary, it could be five, but in this scenario we know they all would have five sub-arrays) with different lengths. Something like:

```
let arrayA = [
              [['a']            , ['b','c','d']],  //lengths  1  and  3 
              [['e','f','g','z'], ['h','i','j']],  //lengths  4  and  3
              [['k','l']        , ['m','n']]       //lengths  2  and  2 
                                                   //sums     7  and  8
             ]
```

We want to add the lengths of each sub-subarray by the index of the sub-array to which they belong:

```
let arrayB = [[7],[8]]
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What's your way to achieve this? And why you think your way is not the best?

Comment: I have none at the moment @RokoC.Buljan

Comment: Create arrayB with 2 values - 0, 0.  Parse arrayA[i][0] and array[i][1] and add the lengths to arrayB[0] and arrayB[1].  Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Also why the result cannot look like `[7, 8]` but instead it's `[[7],[8]]`? We? Who is *we*? **names!** ;)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Because I need to feed the result to a graph later which will digest sub-arrays, and not arrays (there will be an iteration happening later, from which other values in the graph also depend)

Comment: What happens when two people get the right answer?  Can I mark two as correct?

Comment: No, you cannot. You can always wait some days and see who gets the most upvotes from other users... Or do a speed test with the provided answers to see which is actually *best*... Or go for the quickest-to-answer... Or go for the most readable... Or go for the more compact one... Up entirely to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to summarize the array. Use `forEach` to loop thru the inner array.

```js
let arrayA = [[["a"],["b","c","d"]],[["e","f","g","z"],["h","i","j"]],[["k","l"],["m","n"]]];

let result = arrayA.reduce((c, v) => {
  v.forEach((o, i) => {
    c[i] = c[i] || [0];
    c[i][0] += o.length;
  })
  return c;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the array by takinng the lenght property for mapping the sum. Then wrap the results in another array.

```js
var array = [[['a'], ['b', 'c', 'd']], [['e', 'f', 'g', 'z'], ['h', 'i', 'j',]], [['k', 'l'], ['m', 'n']]],
    result = array
        .reduce((r, a) => a.map(({ length }, i) => (r[i] || 0) + length), [])
        .map(a => [a]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new array of the length of only first sub array from original array.
Then use slice to create another array comprising of elem from index 1 till its length from original array.

Then use `forEach` and use the `index`

```js
let arrayA = [
  [
    ['a'],
    ['b', 'c', 'd']
  ],
  [
    ['e', 'f', 'g', 'z'],
    ['h', 'i', 'j', ]
  ],
  [
    ['k', 'l'],
    ['m', 'n']
  ]
]

let initialElem = arrayA[0].map((item) => {
  return [item.length]
})
let secElem = arrayA.slice(1, arrayA.length).forEach(function(item, index) {
  if (Array.isArray(item)) {
    item.forEach(function(elem, index2) {
      initialElem[index2][0] = initialElem[index2][0] + elem.length
    })
  }

})
console.log(initialElem)
```